# SQL Server: Round values of dynamic columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql, rounding, dynamic-columns

I have a question relating to round values from dynamic columns.

I am dynamically (Over past X days) creating a list of player with their daily score and I would like to round these scores with this kind of format `ROUND(Score, 2)`. Here is my query:

```
DECLARE @Column AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @SQL    AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  [Player], [Start], [Average]
INTO #DbTemp1
FROM [PlayerScoreByWeek]
WHERE [Start] >= DateAdd(DAY, -7, GETDATE())

SELECT @Column = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME([Start])
                    FROM        #DbTemp1
                    GROUP BY    [Start]
                    ORDER BY    [Start] FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

SET @SQL = 'SELECT [Player],' + @Column + '
                INTO #DbTemp2
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT [Player], [Start], [Average]
                    FROM #DbTemp1
                ) AS SourceTable
                PIVOT
                (
                    AVG([Average])
                    FOR [Start] IN (' + @Column + ')
                ) AS PivotTable
                ORDER BY Len([Player]), Player
                SELECT * FROM #DbTemp2'
EXECUTE(@SQL)
```

The current output is as follows:

```
Player    2014-02-24    2014-02-25    2014-02-26    2014-02-27    2014-02-28    2014-03-01    2014-03-02 
------    ----------    ----------    ----------    ----------    ----------    ----------    ----------
Carl       26.21654      55.1542       12.29612      29.16546       32.4556      21.1485        48.3652
Gene       46.13444      29.3298       16.31642      12.86592       65.6235      52.8525        31.5915
Kim        25.69554      39.5986       32.23184      34.55685       59.2125      12.2316        29.1242
```

And this is the desired output:

```
Player    2014-02-24    2014-02-25    2014-02-26    2014-02-27    2014-02-28    2014-03-01    2014-03-02 
------    ----------    ----------    ----------    ----------    ----------    ----------    ----------
Carl        26.22          55.15        12.30         29.17          32.46         21.14        48.37
Gene        46.13          29.33        16.32         12.87          65.62         52.85        31.59
Kim         25.70          39.60        32.23         34.56          59.21         12.23        29.12
```

Given that the columns are created dynamically it is not possible to use the round function inside the '@SQL' query.
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another variable for your outputs - eg:

```
DECLARE @Column AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @Output nvarchar(max), @SQL    AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  [Player], [Start], [Average] INTO #DbTemp1 FROM [PlayerScoreByWeek] 
WHERE [Start] >= DateAdd(DAY, -7, GETDATE())

SELECT @Column = STUFF((SELECT ','+ QUOTENAME([Start])
                FROM        #DbTemp1
                GROUP BY    [Start]
                ORDER BY    [Start] FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,''),
       @Output = STUFF((SELECT ', round('+ QUOTENAME([Start])+',2) as ' + QUOTENAME([Start])
                FROM        #DbTemp1
                GROUP BY    [Start]
                ORDER BY    [Start] FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')


SET @SQL = 'SELECT [Player],' + @Output + '
            INTO #dbTemp2            
            FROM
            (
                SELECT [Player], [Start], [Average]
                FROM #DbTemp1
            ) AS SourceTable
            PIVOT
            (
                AVG([Average])
                FOR [Start] IN (' + @Column + ')
            ) AS PivotTable
            ORDER BY Len([Player]), Player;
            select * from #DbTemp2'
 EXECUTE(@SQL)
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I didn't think about creating another variable. It works great !